# Multiply product shipping price X quantity

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shipping-method, product-quantity

can somebody could help me correct this code?

I am trying to enable this : individual product shipping price gets multiplied by its quantity. It works good when there is only one product in the cart. But when there is multiple, it just doubles the total of shipping price of the both products whenever I increase the quantity of one or other. I cant enable this function from woocommerce side because I am using flexible shipping plugin and it doesnt allow me to type in *[qty] in price.

```
// Modify shipping cost based on quantity for each item
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'modify_shipping_cost_based_on_quantity', 10, 2);
function modify_shipping_cost_based_on_quantity($rates, $package)
{
    foreach ($rates as $rate_key => $rate) {
        foreach ($package['contents'] as $item) {
            $quantity = $item['quantity'];
            $new_cost = $rate->cost * $quantity;

            // Calculate the difference between the original cost and the new cost
            $cost_difference = $new_cost - $rate->cost;

            $rates[$rate_key]->cost += $cost_difference;
            $rates[$rate_key]->formatted_cost = wc_price($rates[$rate_key]->cost);
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have revisited your code and added also shipping taxes cost missing part, to make it work as you expect.

Try the following code replacement:

```php
// Change shipping cost based on quantity for each item
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'shipping_cost_based_on_quantity', 10, 2);
function shipping_cost_based_on_quantity($rates, $package)
{
    // Loop through shipping rates
    foreach ($rates as $rate_key => $rate) {
        if (isset($rate->cost)) {
            $quantity = 0; // Initializing
            $has_taxes = false; // Initializing
            $taxes     = array(); // Initializing

            // Loop Through the shipping package for this rates
            foreach ($package['contents'] as $item) {
                $quantity += $item['quantity'];
            }
            $rates[$rate_key]->cost *= $quantity;
            $rates[$rate_key]->formatted_cost = wc_price($rate->cost * $quantity);

            // Loop through taxes array (change taxes rate cost if enabled)
            foreach ($rate->taxes as $key => $tax){
                if( $tax > 0 ){
                    $taxes[$key] = $tax * $quantity; // Set the new tax cost in the array
                    $has_taxes   = true; // Enabling tax changes
                }
            }
            // set array of shipping tax cost
            if( $has_taxes ) {
                $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Comment: Thank you. The code works, but it looks like it multiplies the total price of the shipping than the individual price of shipping for each product. For example, the total of shipping price for both products is now 20usd, the code makes it 40usd. I hope I explained it well.

Comment: @ravis Not so clear at all :) … You should update your question with a complete priced example (settings) and interactions (different scenarios), saying what you have without the code customization, and what you expect to have with it.